# JMeter Boundary Extractor Ignore Case

Tags: jmeter

I would like to use a Boundary Extractor but be able to ignore the case of the boundaries, is this possible?

I know it is possible to do that on Response Assertions and Regular Expression Extractors.

Answer (score 0):

As per JMeter 4.0 it is not possible with the Boundary Extractor, however you can achieve this using Regular Expression Extractor, the relevant regular expression would be something like:

```
(?i)leftboundary(?s)(.*)(?i)rightboundary
```

It will match what is between the `leftboundary` and the `rightboundary` no matter whatever case will be in the input string and/or in the regular expression itself:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Case Insensitive Boundaries]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Regex Cheat Sheet - QuickStart](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)